# cwm window manager - extend "exec program" search path with custom directories

Tags: window-managers, openbsd

I am using cwm on OpenBSD 5.6 and have got my scripts in my ~/bin folder.
In my .zshrc the PATH is also exetended with

```
.zshrc:
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

If I spawn the "exec program" dialog with M-? , my scripts do not appear in the dialog.

I cannot find any docs whether cwm sources any user-specific dot-rc files. Exporting the new PATH in .profile does not heled. Also in the .cwmrc there seems to be no config option to extend the search path.

My question:
How can I configure cwm to look also in my ~/bin to find executables there?

BTW my question **does not** concern the "command" config for the application menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it and it works fine for me, although I use ksh and not zsh but that shouldn't matter. A few things to look out for:

1. your script has to be executable
2. setting the PATH manually in an xterm while already running cwm won't work, because export only exports to children and is not visible by cwm
3. editing .zshrc may require you to logout (and in again) for changes to become visible (not 100% certain on this, since it depends on your setup), unless you're running it manually afterwards

Comment: additional missing peace to @ci_ is mentioned [in the OpenBSD Forum](http://marc.info/?l=openbsd-misc&m=142829426523976&w=2): In the `~/.xsession` the ENV has to be set or the whole `~/.profile` has to be sourced, so that cwm recognizes the new `$PATH`